# canvas drawing issue where paint needs to be restricted by black sketch

Tags: android, canvas

I need to create the painting application for the kids where kid can colour inside the black bordered sketch of any image

But, I am struck with the problem,that colouring can come outside the black bordering of the image...which i don't want to.Please guys help me to find out how to restrict the colouring by user within the black border of sketch

Also, I want that no colour should cover the black border.it should be inside the border.

I can post my code if required.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Canvas clipPath and use the clipping built in to android to limit the 'coloring' of the kid/user to the regions you specify.  You can then draw your objects as layers, kid/user colored layer on bottom, your sketch on top.

Comment: hi @spartygw...thanks for your suggestion. It will be immense help if you could provide any such snippets or links for the same..Please help me in this.

Comment: Finally..i have implemented it using mask bitmap and right usage of Portet.Duff mode

Answer (score 0):

Finally..i have implemented it using mask bitmap and right usage of Portet.Duff mode